# CSS: Two texts side by side, one fits content, the other shrinks and overflows until min-width then wraps

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a title and a `url` one after the other and I want them to be side by side until they fit on the container width. When they can't fit side by side I want the `url` to shrink and overflow, until it reaches its min-width, then it can wrap.

Within the same container there are other elements that, if possible, I'd like to keep untouched, behaving like inline or flex items.

I tried to achieve this with flexbox, which had to have `flex-wrap: wrap` in order to make the subsequent elements flow, but the url would either shrink and make the date element come up on the first row (`flex-basis: 0`) or expand too much until it wrapped to the following line (`flex-basis: some%`).
I tried to use float and clear, but couldn't get it to work.

- Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

**desired result**

[image]

- Here's what I'm getting with `flexbox`:

**`url` not expanding**

[image]

- Here's what I want when the available space is less than the url min-width:

**`url` wrapping to next line**

[image]

Here's the relevant html code:

```
<div class="section" data-section="header">
    <h5 class="section-title" style="display: none;">Section title</h5>

    <div class="field" data-field="title">
        <span class="field-label" style="display: none;">Field label</span>
        <span class="field-value">
            Some variable length, possibly quite long text here
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="field" data-field="link">
        <span class="field-label" style="display: none;">Link</span>
        <span class="field-value">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/some-path/a-variable-length-and-possibly-quite-long-url-here.html">
                https://www.example.com/some-path/a-variable-length-and-possibly-quite-long-url-here.html
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="field" data-field="date">
        <span class="field-label">Date</span>
        <span class="field-value">2018-05-03 00:00:00</span>
    </div>
    [...]
</div>
```

And the current CSS:

```
.section[data-section=header] .field {
    display: inline;
}
.section[data-section=header] .field[data-field=title] {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 0.8;
}
.section[data-section=header] .field[data-field=link] {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.section[data-section=header] .field[data-field=link] .field-value {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: calc(100% - .8em);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: -.1em;
}
.section[data-section=header] .field[data-field=link]::before {
    content: "[";
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.section[data-section=header] .field[data-field=link]::after {
    content: "]\000A";
    white-space: pre;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.section[data-section=header] .field[data-field=status]::after {
    content: "\000A";
    white-space: pre;
}
.section[data-section=header] .field[data-field=title]::after {
    content: " ";
    line-height: 0px;
    font-size: 2.8em;
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this without resorting to edit the html layout or isolating the title and `url` into their own container?